# Arithmetic shift to divide by ODD number - Microprogrammed Control

Tags: assembly, architecture, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to write the following instruction:

AC <-- AC / 3.

I know I can use arithmetic shift right in order to preform division by 2 but how can I preform a division by an odd number using only the possible instrcutions in microprogrammed control (micro-instructions).

Thank you

Comment: Chapter 7 - Microprogrammed Control in Mano's book.

Comment: Is AC divisible by 3? If not, how do you want the result rounded? Is AC unsigned or signed? If signed, do you use 2's complement or 1s complement? What instructions can be used?

Comment: Is it possible to preform this division using only SHR, SHL microinstruction? in microprogrammed control you can only use SHR, SHL, XOR, AND and such

Comment: Suppose AC is divisible by 3. AC is in 2's complement.

Comment: If you wanted to divide by two in this architecure you would write: SHR once and then AC would be divided by 2.

Comment: How wide is the register?

Comment: Is there a multiplication instruction?

Comment: SHL would multiply AC by 2.

Comment: Yes you have add and sub.

Comment: ADD: AC <- AC + DR, SUB: AC <-- AC - DR. DR is another register which can hold a constant for exmaple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another answer suggests divide by two, multiply by 2/3.

If you can multiply by 2/3, you can multiply by 1/3 just as easily (1/3 = .0101010101.. in binary) and skip the divide by two.

To multiply by 1/3, you can right shift the dividend *two positions* (corresponding to to multiplying by .01!) and add to an accumulator.  Repeat the multiply (er, right shift twice, multiplying by .0001, .000001, ...) and add as many times as you need to handle the maximum number of bits you expect the dividend to have.   Be careful about dividend bits that "fall off the end"; you either need a double-precision shifter/accumulator, or you need to scale the dividend by a positive power of two corresponding to the number of bits before you start to avoid loss of precision, assuming you have enough spare bits.

Dividing by other constants can be accomplished by multiplying by the bit that make up their reciprocal.  It isn't quite so neat but the ideas are the same.  You can figure out a variant of this that computes modulo (remainder) after dividing by a constant. Both of these are common tricks in compiler-generated code, too.

Comment: Oh jeez, you're right. I guess I just had the div-by-2 bit shift on my mind after reading the problem description.

Comment: I wouldn't say "right" as much as "old".  I first did this in a Data General Nova in 1974 to help a guy write a fast interrupt routine, to find out which 3-word queue entry was interesting. FWIW, Knuth's book on "Seminumerical algorithms" (published around then) is an absolute treasure trove of ideas on how to do various kinds of arithmetic like this.

Comment: Thanks Ira. I'm behind you but not too far. I have the Knuth books, but it's been quite awhile since I've read them. ;)

Comment: I tried to do this technique on the following number : 24 (0011000 in 8-bit binary). Now I want to divide by 3 so I shift right twice and I get 0000110 which equals 6 whereas 24/3=8. What do I miss?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't explain myself correctly. I mean how do I handle the double precision using only AC and DR. No double precision or such. In the case I wrote above I'll get 24/3 = 7 instead of 8.

Comment: What do you mean by scale the dividend by a positive power of two?

Comment: One more thing, How do you know 1/3 equals to two shr and add to AC. If I wanted to divide by 5 or 7 what would be difference?

Comment: Read dwelch's answer.  He shows examples of scaling, whose purpose is to keep the dividend bits all in the same register.  You can only do this if you know the dividend is small compared to the size of the register.  If you don't scale you need to a double precision register scheme; surely you can shift right AC, with a bit falling off the end, and shift that bit into the top of DR.  Any decently microprogrammable engine will be able to do this.  You still need a place to put the accumulated answer, either some 3rd register or memory reads/writes (not typical in a microprogramming problem).

Comment: ... for multiply by 1/3, the excuse for right-shift-two is the bit pattern for 1/3:  .01010101... = .01 + .0001 + .0000001 + ...  To multiply by .01 binary a right shift by two is sufficient; to multiply by .0001, take the twice-rightshifted result, and right-shift twice again.   You need to learn to see patterns.

Comment: To divide by 5 or 7, you need to compute the binary expansion of the reciprocal (e.g., of 1/5 or 1/7).  The bits tell you how many times to shift, and when to add.  That's the point of dwelch's remark, "it is basically grade school stuff", and the point about Knuth's text books, which explain all this in wonderful technical detail.

Comment: Regarding "I tried to do this technique" and got the wrong answer:  You didn't multiply by 1/3.  You multiple by 1/4 (= .01).  You have to *repeat* the process, without losing bits, or you are losing precision and getting bad results.  Technically, 24_10=0011000_2 * (.01_2 +.0001_2 + .000001_2...) = 110.000_2 + 001.100_2 + 000.011_2 + = 111.1111 ... which 7.99_10.  To get the *right* answer to N places, you need to round because you have only finite precision, but 1/3 is infinitely long when expanded.  The "001.100" shows that you need double precision to track the fractional bits, or scale.

Answer (score 3):

To divide by 3, divide by `2` first, then multiply by `2/3`. In binary, `2/3` is `0.101010101...`. If you have a shift through carry capability, you can:

1. Q <- Dividend SHR 2 (divide Dividend by 2)
2. Multiply the value Q by 1010101010101010 by a shift/add loop, resulting in a 32-bit Q value (a top 16-bit word and bottom 16-bit word)
3. Test the high bit of the lower 16-bit word. If it's `1`, add `1` to the high 16-bit word of Q
4. The quotient of `Dividend/3` is the top 16-bit word of Q

It's a bit of shifting and adding, though. Also, you might need `1010101010101011` instead of `1010101010101010` due to rounding. I modeled this method quickly in Ruby and it seemed to work on a couple of simple cases.

You might also be able to run a straight division algorithm (shift through carry, compare, subtract,...) on binary `11` into `Dividend`. You'd need a couple of spare registers for that. But it's usable on any divisor, not just `3`. That's just microcoding a `div` instruction.

Answer (score 3):

Upvote Ira and mbratch, I am simply expanding on their answer to understand how and why it works.

It is basically grade school stuff...Remember base 10 multiplies:

```
  1234
*   11
=======
  1234  (1*1234)
+12340  (10*1234)
=======
 13574
```

binary makes that much easier because the digits can only be 1 or 0 no 2, 3, 4, etc...

```
  1111
*   11
=========
  1111 (1*1111)
+11110 (10*1111)
====== 
101101
```

so if I have some generic bits xyz, multiplied by 5 then

```
   xyz
*  101
========
   xyz
+xyz00
=======
```

because 5 = 4+1 = 2^2 + 2^0 = 1<<2 + 1<<0 then some variable n*5 = (n<<2) + (n<<0)

What is the binary for 1/3rd?  Well why not use long division from grade school?

```
      0.01010101
     -----------
   11)1.00000000
      1          bring down the 1
     -0          0 times 3 first digit is a 0
    ==== 
       10        bring down the 0
      -00        0 times 3, second digit is 0
      ====
       100       bring down the 0
      - 11       1 times 3, next digit is a 1
      ====
         10      result 1, bring down 0
        - 0      0 times 3, next digit is a 0
        === 
         100     result is 2, bring down the 0
        - 11     1 times 3, next digit is a 1
        ==== 
           10
```

and the pattern begins to repeat 0.01010101...

So if a multiply by 5 means binary 101*n = (n<<2) + (n<<0) because the non-zero bits are at the 2^0 and 2^2 locations.  Then if you do the multiplication as we did with 5 above it doesnt matter if there is a decimal place.  0.1 is 2 to the power -1, 0.01 is 2 to the power -2 and so on so  binary 1.01 times N would be (n<<0) + (n>>2).

And finally multiplying by 1/3rd which is approximated with 0.0101010101.... that means

```
result = (n>>2) + (n>>4) + (n>>6) + ...
```

Which as pointed out by someone else you can do that in a loop, something along the lines of.

```
result = 0;
while(n)
{
   n>>=2;
   result+=n;
}
```

Just like in base 10, when you divide by something that has a factor of 3 in it you get an infinitely repeating number, you have the same problem in base 2, an infinite repeating number.  Just like base 10 where sometimes you want 0.6666666 to be 0.666667 depending on how many digits, but not round 0.333333 you might want to round your divisor and have extra bit in there 0.0101011  or something like that.

divthree.c

```
unsigned int divthree ( unsigned int x )
{
    unsigned int y;

    y=0;
    x<<=16;
    while(x)
    {
        x>>=2;
        y+=x;
    }
```

//        y+=0x8000; //round up?
        y>>=16;
        return(y);
    }

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern unsigned int divthree ( unsigned int );
unsigned int next_prand ( unsigned int x )
{
    if(x&1)
    {
        x=x>>1;
        x=x^0xBF9EC099;
    }
    else
    {
        x=x>>1;
    }
    return(x);
}
int main ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra,rb,rc,rd,re;
    unsigned int p;

    unsigned int prand;

    prand=0x12345;

    for(ra=0;ra<20;ra++)
    {
        prand=next_prand(prand);
        p=prand&0xFFFF;
        rb=p/3;
        rc=divthree(p);
        rd=divthree(p+1);
        re=divthree(p+2);

        printf("%u %u ",p,rb);
        printf("(%u %d) ",rc,rc-rb);
        printf("(%u %d) ",rd,rd-rb);
        printf("(%u %d) ",re,re-rb);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

so running the above, without doing the rounding...

```
6931 (6931 0) (6931 0) (6932 1) 
19798 (19798 0) (19798 0) (19799 1) 
20822 (20821 -1) (20822 0) (20822 0) 
10411 (10410 -1) (10411 0) (10411 0) 
21640 (21640 0) (21640 0) (21640 0) 
16241 (16241 0) (16241 0) (16242 1) 
13627 (13627 0) (13627 0) (13628 1) 
12224 (12223 -1) (12224 0) (12224 0) 
6112 (6111 -1) (6112 0) (6112 0) 
3056 (3055 -1) (3056 0) (3056 0) 
12450 (12450 0) (12450 0) (12451 1) 
6225 (6225 0) (6225 0) (6225 0) 
3112 (3112 0) (3112 0) (3113 1) 
1556 (1556 0) (1556 0) (1556 0) 
6274 (6274 0) (6274 0) (6274 0) 
8563 (8563 0) (8563 0) (8563 0) 
4281 (4281 0) (4281 0) (4282 1) 
7642 (7642 0) (7642 0) (7642 0) 
20170 (20169 -1) (20170 0) (20170 0) 
10085 (10084 -1) (10085 0) (10085 0)
```

that second set,  divthree(n+1) is right on so far...

to improve on the multiply by this irrational number, notice how the division routine gave lots more precision (didnt need to be that extreme) assuming 16 bit numbers using 32 bit math operations.

Not doing that

```
unsigned int divthree ( unsigned int x )
{
    unsigned int y;

    y=0;
    //x<<=16;
    while(x)
    {
        x>>=2;
        y+=x;
    }
    //y+=0x8000;
    //y>>=16;
    return(y);
}
```

Not as accurate as one would hope.

```
20795 6931 (6928 -3) (6929 -2) (6929 -2) 
59396 19798 (19796 -2) (19796 -2) (19796 -2) 
62466 20822 (20819 -3) (20819 -3) (20820 -2) 
31233 10411 (10408 -3) (10408 -3) (10408 -3) 
64921 21640 (21635 -5) (21635 -5) (21635 -5) 
48725 16241 (16237 -4) (16237 -4) (16237 -4) 
40883 13627 (13622 -5) (13623 -4) (13623 -4) 
36672 12224 (12221 -3) (12221 -3) (12221 -3) 
18336 6112 (6109 -3) (6109 -3) (6109 -3) 
9168 3056 (3053 -3) (3053 -3) (3053 -3) 
37352 12450 (12447 -3) (12447 -3) (12447 -3) 
18676 6225 (6222 -3) (6222 -3) (6222 -3) 
9338 3112 (3109 -3) (3109 -3) (3110 -2) 
4669 1556 (1553 -3) (1553 -3) (1553 -3) 
18823 6274 (6271 -3) (6272 -2) (6272 -2) 
25690 8563 (8560 -3) (8560 -3) (8561 -2) 
12845 4281 (4278 -3) (4278 -3) (4278 -3) 
22927 7642 (7638 -4) (7640 -2) (7640 -2) 
60510 20170 (20165 -5) (20165 -5) (20167 -3) 
30255 10085 (10080 -5) (10082 -3) (10082 -3)
```

(can start to appreciate what a floating point unit does or doesnt do for you).

If you try shifting, one then two then three then four, this matches the shift 16 from above.

```
unsigned int divthree ( unsigned int x )
{
    unsigned int y;

    y=0;
    x<<=4;
    while(x)
    {
        x>>=2;
        y+=x;
    }
    y>>=4;
    return(y);
}
```

you would need those extra 4 bits of headroom depending on your numbers or the instruction set/registers.

So any time you want to multiply by (or divide by) a constant that is known at/before compile time you can use this simple method of shifting and adding.  but you have to deal with accuracy if the division is by an irrational number.

Comment: this while loop only works for positive numbers, obviously.  For negative numbers it has to be an arithmetic shift rather than logical, and you know ahead of time how many times to go through the loop anyway.

Comment: Note: It is pretty easy to confirm that .010101... is 1/3 in binary.  If you multiply by 3, you get  .1111111...  out to infinity, which is indistingisable from 1.0.

Comment: Amazing how much effort you put to help. Thank you very much!